# how to convert a class tuple to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have multiple tuple rows , that needs to convert into pandas dataframe

```
sample_data=

(1, 'stackoverflow, tags, users,count')

(2, 'gmail, outlook,apps,users,count')

(3, 'digital, marketing,credentials')

(4, 'langugaes,python,c,java')

(5, 'slack,teams')
```

I tried `data =pd.Dataframe(sample_data)` but throwing error

output should be

```
column1=index , column2=research_topics

  index    research_topics

   1    'stackoverflow, tags, users ,count'

   2    'Gmail outlook, apps, users, count'

   3    'digital marketing, credentials'

   4    'languages, python,c,java'

   5     'slack, teams'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `from_records` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)). It can convert a list of tuples into a dataframe.

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['index ', 'research_topics'])
```

and if you want "index" to be index, use `.set_index('index')'

(assuming here `data` is a list of tuples)

Comment: I got TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable , since the format is in tuple & not commas after closing each element

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your sample_data as a list of tuples:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_data=[(1, 'stackoverflow, tags, users,count'),

(2, 'gmail, outlook,apps,users,count'),

(3, 'digital, marketing,credentials'),

(4, 'langugaes,python,c,java'),

(5, 'slack,teams')]
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data, columns=['index', 'research_topics'])

print(df)
```

Comment: did it solved your issue?

Comment: not yet resolved . could you pitch in & help here

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? did you try to wrap it as a list of tuples?